# Short list of the IMO 2003

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

Let $b$ a integer greater than $5$. For each positive integer $n$, consider the number

$$x_n=\underbrace{11\ldots1}_{n-1}\ \underbrace{22\ldots 2}_{n}\ 5$$

written in base $b$. Prove that the following condition holds if and only if $b=10$:

There exists a positive integer $M$ such that for any integer $n$ greater than M, the numbre $x_n$ is a perfect square.

Comment: $$x_n=\underbrace{11...1}_{n-1}\ \underbrace{22...2}_{n}\ 5=5+2b\frac{b^{n+1}-1}{b-1}+b^n\frac{b^n-1}{b-1}$$

Comment: I wrote $x_{n+1} = x_n+b^{n+1}+b^{2n}+b^{2n+1}$, then I found a expression for x_n, but I don't know what do before that... a try a expert factorization but doesn't help

Comment: https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=19129&sid=b836022c7798094346e648a702b3627d#p19129